# Значения веса вариативного товара woocommerce, из значения атрибута

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как создать такой хук woocommerce, чтобы при отсутствии значения веса вариативного товара, значение подтягивалось из значения атрибута

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если я не путаю, это происходит автоматом. Только не из атрибута а на закладке Основное.

Comment: То, что Вы хотите немного странно, для этого можно попробовать фильтр woocommerce_product_variation_get_weight с 2 параметрами. Примеров не нашёл, но есть исходник, где он живёт cв файле class-wc-product-variation.php, в функции get_weight

Comment: Спасибо, @Sergio